# Where does tor look for directory servers?

Tags: configuration, relays, exit-relays, directory

I'm working on a project and need to determine how tor determines directory authorities. Looking at the source of version **0.2.8.0-alpha-dev (git-d015c70a118e4357)** in file **or/config.c** there are a number of default directories:

```
/** List of default directory authorities */

static const char *default_authorities[] = {
  "moria1 orport=9101 "
    "v3ident=D586D18309DED4CD6D57C18FDB97EFA96D330566 "
    "128.31.0.39:9131 9695 DFC3 5FFE B861 329B 9F1A B04C 4639 7020 CE31",
  "tor26 orport=443 "
    "v3ident=14C131DFC5C6F93646BE72FA1401C02A8DF2E8B4 "
    "86.59.21.38:80 847B 1F85 0344 D787 6491 A548 92F9 0493 4E4E B85D",
  "dizum orport=443 "
    "v3ident=E8A9C45EDE6D711294FADF8E7951F4DE6CA56B58 "
    "194.109.206.212:80 7EA6 EAD6 FD83 083C 538F 4403 8BBF A077 587D D755",
  "Tonga orport=443 bridge "
    "82.94.251.203:80 4A0C CD2D DC79 9508 3D73 F5D6 6710 0C8A 5831 F16D",
  "gabelmoo orport=443 "
    "v3ident=ED03BB616EB2F60BEC80151114BB25CEF515B226 "
    "131.188.40.189:80 F204 4413 DAC2 E02E 3D6B CF47 35A1 9BCA 1DE9 7281",
  "dannenberg orport=443 "
    "v3ident=585769C78764D58426B8B52B6651A5A71137189A "
    "193.23.244.244:80 7BE6 83E6 5D48 1413 21C5 ED92 F075 C553 64AC 7123",
  "urras orport=80 "
    "v3ident=80550987E1D626E3EBA5E5E75A458DE0626D088C "
    "208.83.223.34:443 0AD3 FA88 4D18 F89E EA2D 89C0 1937 9E0E 7FD9 4417",
  "maatuska orport=80 "
    "v3ident=49015F787433103580E3B66A1707A00E60F2D15B "
    "171.25.193.9:443 BD6A 8292 55CB 08E6 6FBE 7D37 4836 3586 E46B 3810",
  "Faravahar orport=443 "
    "v3ident=EFCBE720AB3A82B99F9E953CD5BF50F7EEFC7B97 "
    "154.35.175.225:80 CF6D 0AAF B385 BE71 B8E1 11FC 5CFF 4B47 9237 33BC",
  "longclaw orport=443 "
    "v3ident=23D15D965BC35114467363C165C4F724B64B4F66 "
    "199.254.238.52:80 74A9 1064 6BCE EFBC D2E8 74FC 1DC9 9743 0F96 8145",
  NULL
};
```

I've placed a breakpoint on the function using these values and it is not executed (immediately) at runtime. Running wireshark the following transcript is shown:

[image: tor packet capture]

However, the address **193.11.114.46** is not present within the source code (at least in plain text/unencoded form). Using strace doesn't reveal any useful information either:

```
    $ strace -e poll,select,connect,recvfrom,sendto ./tor
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 10)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 10)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
Dec 26 11:37:35.625 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.0-alpha-dev running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1k and Zlib 1.2.8.
Dec 26 11:37:35.625 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 26 11:37:35.625 [notice] This version is not a stable Tor release. Expect more bugs than usual.
Dec 26 11:37:35.625 [notice] Configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
sendto(3, "\24\0\0\0\22\0\1\3O\302~V\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
sendto(3, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3P\302~V\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9), sin_addr=inet_addr("18.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
Dec 26 11:37:35.629 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 26 11:37:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Dec 26 11:37:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
poll([?] 0x7ffe952f4b00, 1, 10)         = 1
connect(8, {...}, 16)                   = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
sendto(9, 0x7ffe952f49b0, 20, 0, {...}, 12) = 20
sendto(9, 0x7ffe952f49b0, 20, 0, {...}, 12) = 20
sendto(9, 0x7ffe952f49b0, 20, 0, {...}, 12) = 20
sendto(9, 0x7ffe952f49b0, 20, 0, {...}, 12) = 20
Dec 26 11:37:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Dec 26 11:37:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Dec 26 11:37:37.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Dec 26 11:37:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Where can I find the list of predefined directory authorities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.tor creates a directory **.tor** in the home directory (on Linux).

```
$ ls ~/.tor
cached-certs  cached-microdesc-consensus  cached-microdescs  cached-microdescs.new  lock  state
$ grep -Rn 193.11.114.46
cached-microdesc-consensus:24929:r mdfnet3 uD3BVY8NNDU7uZLvk6/q/bImpz4 2015-12-26 11:02:15 193.11.114.46 9003 9032
```

The directory authorities above are used on the first run (when the **.tor** directory has not been created yet).

Comment: they are not there, because in **.tor** folder is nothing at the very beginning, but the tor is bootstrapping itself. The directories that are mentioned in the question are inside the tor source code

Answer (score 1):

Actually the servers are listed in source you have discovered. And a lot of nodes are running the mirrors for signed directory data, so in .tor folder you will have a lot of *mirrors*, but the *directories* are hard coded as far as I know